# How to remove Y Axis Titles and replace them with Legend Titles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just started R programming 2 weeks ago and i have a case study plot with 1 x axis and 2 y axis... I tried everything i can for 48 hours to replace Title with Legend... And i couldn't figure out what's the issue, Hopefully i can get help input from you guys.

PLOT:

```
ggplot(libya_covid, aes(x=date)) +
  
  geom_line( aes(y=new_tests), size=2, color='blue') + 
  geom_line( aes(y=new_cases / 1), size=2, color='darkorange') +
  
  xlab("Date")+
  
  scale_y_continuous(
    
    # Features of the first axis
    name = "New Tests",
    
    # Add a second axis and specify its features
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, name= "New Cases")
  ) + 
  
  theme_bw() +
  
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = 'blue', size=13),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = 'darkorange', size=13)
  ) +
  
  ggtitle("New Tests Versus New Cases Analysis")
```

[image: Now I just Want To Remove Y Titles from Right & Left and ADD Simple Legend On Top Left]

Now I just Want To Remove Y Titles from Right & Left and ADD Simple Legend On Top Left

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to copy the data to test and verify solutions. [MRE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ggplot2 legends reflect aesthetics or scales. This said, if you want to have a legend you have to map on aesthetics.

To get a legend depicting the different colored lines you could map a constant value on the color aesthetic and then assign your desired colors to these constants using `scale_color_manual`.

To get rid of the labels remove the `name=`s from `scale_y_continious` and using `labs` set `y=NULL` which means remove the y axis title. Finally, you could position the legend via `theme` options `legend.position` and `legend.justification`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

#### Use economics dataset as example data
libya_covid <- ggplot2::economics
names(libya_covid)[4:5] <- c("new_tests", "new_cases")
####

ggplot(libya_covid, aes(x=date)) +
  geom_line( aes(y=new_tests, color='New Tests'), size=2) + 
  geom_line( aes(y=new_cases / 1, color='New Cases'), size=2) +
  labs(x = "Date", y = NULL, color = NULL, title = "New Tests Versus New Cases Analysis") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1)
  ) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("New Tests" ='blue', "New Cases" ='darkorange')) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = 'blue', size=13),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = 'darkorange', size=13),
    legend.position = c(0.05, .95),
    legend.justification = c(0.05, .95)
  )
```

[image]